# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'path'

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I wanted to use the `logging` module. Here's my code:

```py
from datatime import datatime
import logging
output_dir = fr'./{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}.log'  # fr"" is f"" + r"" 
logging.basicConfig(filename=output_dir, level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

But when I run it, this error will raise:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PaliProx\Desktop\Projects\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(filename=output_dir, level=logging.DEBUG)
  File "C:\Users\PaliProx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 2003, in basicConfig
    h = FileHandler(filename, mode,
  File "C:\Users\PaliProx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1146, in __init__ 
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "C:\Users\PaliProx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1175, in _open    
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\PaliProx\\Desktop\\Project\\2021-09-09 18:28:27.log'
```

What's the problem with my code that raises this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows filenames cannot have colons in them. Try this instead:

`output_dir = fr'./{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")}.log'`